# JavaScript push data to array

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm new for javascript and try to push some data to the array as below.

```
async function mailSend(callback) {
User = [];
for (let scriptData of automatedScriptData.dataList) {
    let userData = {
        email: scriptData["Business Email"],
        password: "acc0unt@123",
        name: scriptData["First Name"] + " " + scriptData["Last Name"],
        firstName:scriptData["First Name"],
        title: scriptData["Title"],
        timeZone: scriptData["Time Zone"],
        location: scriptData["Country"],
        company: scriptData["Company"]
    };


    User.push(userData.firstName);
    console.log(User);

    }

}
```

My result as below.

**[ 'Brock' ]
[ 'Brock', 'Kristian' ]**

But I want just
**[ 'Brock', 'Kristian' ]**

Can anyone help me to solve that issue.

Comment: Your code works fine. Move the `console.log(User)` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have added `console.log(User);` inside `for` loop. Move this out of the `for` loop you will get the desired output.

Try this:

```
async function mailSend(callback) {
User = [];
  for (let scriptData of automatedScriptData.dataList) {
    let userData = {
      email: scriptData["Business Email"],
      password: "acc0unt@123",
      name: scriptData["First Name"] + " " + scriptData["Last Name"],
      firstName:scriptData["First Name"],
      title: scriptData["Title"],
      timeZone: scriptData["Time Zone"],
      location: scriptData["Country"],
      company: scriptData["Company"]
    };    
    User.push(userData.firstName);
  }    
}
console.log(User);
```